# HTTP POST Data from Arduino to Django Database

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, post, arduino

I know it is frowned upon to post questions without code, but I have been stuck for days thinking of how to handle this issue and cant think of a solution.

My setup is this:

1. Arduino Mega w/ 4G + GPS Shield from Cooking Hacks
2. Django Server set up with Python
3. Postgresql Database

Because the 4G + GPS shield has the capability for http commands, I want to use http POST to send gps data to my Django Server and store that information in my Postgresql database. Another thing to keep in mind is I am running a Django test server on my Localhost, so I need to POST to that local host.

Because I am not posting through a form and it is not synchronous I am really confused as to how the Django server is supposed to handle this asynchronous POST. It will look like this (I imagine):

**Arduino (POST) --> Django Server (Localhost) --> Postgresql Database**

So I have 2 questions:

1) In order to successfully send a POST to my local Django Server, should my host be my public router IP and the Port be the same as that which I am running my server on? Is there something else I am missing?

2) Do I need to use Django REST Framework to handle the POST request? if not, how would I implement this in my views.py?

I am trying to get a reference point on the problem in order to visualize how to do it. I DONT need coded solutions. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and if you have any other questions I will be quick to answer.

Comment: If you need to post locally, Phone and host (django server) should be in same wifi. No need of rest framework. Django itself can handle any type of requests.

Comment: I am connecting to the server from a 4G cellular data not wifi, so i am not on the same wifi. Therefore I am unsure as to if my host is the public router IP or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Depends, if your arduino is on the same local network than your Django Server then you don't need a public IP, otherwise you would have to forward your Django Server IP & port so its accesible from internet.

2) Not really, you can do a traditional POST request to a normal view on Django.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I want my Arduino to be POSTing from outside my private network, so I would most likely have to make my IP and port accessible, however, shouldn't port forwarding only be necessary for TCP/UDP? Otherwise I am unsure of how to make them available to the public

Comment: Yes, you can configure your router to forward some ports to a specific machine inside your network, or you can mount your server on a cloud provider like [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which will give you an accessible IP address or domain.